# LOOP: FOR clauses should occur before the loop's main body

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I have this code but I'm getting this error with the answer when running it, does anyone know how to fix it or why am I getting this?

```
(defun pell (n)
  (setq n (+ n 1))
  (loop repeat n
        for current = 0 then next
        and next = 1 then (+ (* 2 next) current)
        collect current))

(print (pell 6))
```

Comment: You need to change `and` with `for`. Each iteration variable must be introduced by its own `for` clause.

Comment: i'm still getting an error

Answer (score 2):

> FOR clauses should occur before the loop's main body

you have a REPEAT clause before the FOR. Lisp complains that FOR should occur **before** the main body.

Thus instead of

```
REPEAT ...
FOR ...
...
```

it is

```
FOR ...
REPEAT ...
...
```

Comment: i got this error WARNING: LOOP: After REPEAT, N is interpreted as a type specification
*** - LOOP: invalid keyword NIL after FOR

Comment: I have no idea what code you have tried to execute. Every error description should come with a reproducible example.

Comment: for before repeat which gives the error WARNING: LOOP: After REPEAT, N is interpreted as a type specification *** - LOOP: invalid keyword NIL after FOR

Comment: I wrote that you should move the REPEAT clause after the FOR clause. After the whole clause. Not just move REPEAT after the word FOR. The FOR clause describes the complete FOR iteration. The complete REPEAT clause needs to be after *all* complete FOR clauses.

Comment: thank you so much, do you think there's something wrong with my calculations because when doing what you said I'm getting a different answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `and` with `for` and move the `repeat` clause after the variable clauses. Each iteration variable must be introduced by its own `for` keyword. Here is the correct version:

```
(defun pell (n)
  (loop for current = 0 then next
        for next = 1 then (+ (* 2 next) current)
        repeat (1+ n)
        collect current))

(pell 6)  ; => (0 1 3 9 27 81 243)
```

**Note:** my previous version with `repeat` before the `for` was accepted without problems by SBCL, but the official syntax requires the `repeat` after the `for` clauses.

At [this page](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) you can find the correct syntax of the `loop` primitive.

An introduction to the `loop` construct can be found [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html).

Comment: the correct list is  (0 1 2 5 12 29 70) not (0 1 3 9 27 81 243), and i got the error twice with this code

Comment: I corrected only the syntax error. If there is an error on the algorithm you can post another question, where you show what you want exactly.

Comment: i'm still getting WARNING: LOOP: FOR clauses should occur before the loop's main body with the corrected code you've posted

Comment: REPEAT needs to be after FOR forms.

Comment: Thanks, @RainerJoswig, I tested the first version in SBCL and that implementation does not cause any error or warning. I’ve corrected now the answer.